# cocos2d-x: phantom bodies collision

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game with cocos2d-x v3.2 where I have blocks falling off the top of the screen. When they reach the ground - they break.
New blocks are created constantly with schedule() invoking generateBlock method. 
New block is created with this code:

```
  newBlock = new Blocks(newPoint, false);
  newBlock->drawBlock(this, BLOCK_ZORDER);
```

and is removed with this code:

```
if(BLOCKS_BITMASK == contact.getShapeA()->getBody()->getCollisionBitmask())
{
    contact.getShapeA()->getBody()->removeFromWorld();
    layer->removeChild(contact.getShapeA()->getBody()->getNode());

}
else
{
    contact.getShapeB()->getBody()->removeFromWorld();
    layer->removeChild(contact.getShapeB()->getBody()->getNode());
}
```

Everything works fine, except that sometimes a block doesn't generate (it neither appear in the CCLog() where I track blocks generation nor on the screen), though the time of generation has come. And that non-existing phantom body collides with ground (which I see due to generated particles and "block hit ground" in the log).

Comment: I'm not sure, could you add more CCLog statements to further narrow down what is happening?

Comment: I've kinda found the problem, though it makes a little sense to me. In my Blocks' constructor I pick a random block type from enum, then parseJsonFile with blokcs' bodies. After that quite big switch-case construction selects necessary block's sprite and body.

Comment: So I replaced scheduled blockGeneration with generation on touch and started experimentation with number of types of blocks and it appeared that if there are less then 5 blocks - they never disappear, more then 5 - sometimes block's sprite disappear. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what was the problem. I didn't use texture cache. I thought cocos2dx v3.2 could autocahe sprites and he actually can, but somehow sprites just didn't cache, so they simply disappeared. After I preloaded them in an init() method of the scene they no longer disappear.